# The data in a table when this code is refreshed in a django server disappers. How to make it so that the code stays and just new rows in db stay?

Tags: python, django

I am running  django server and when I run the server for the first time the code adds the data to the database. Upon running it a second time the data in the database disappears. How do I have it so that everytime the server runs it just adds the new data to the database?

The data in this case is youtube  data

```
import sqlite3

def youtube_data(request):
    # Replace 'YOUR_API_KEY' with your actual YouTube Data API key
    api_key = 'YOUR_API_KEY'
    youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api_key)

    channel_ids = ['CHANNEL_ID_1', 'CHANNEL_ID_2', 'CHANNEL_ID_3']  # Replace with the desired channel IDs

    videos = []
    conn = sqlite3.connect('your_database.sqlite3')  # Replace 'your_database.sqlite3' with your SQLite database file path

    try:
        for channel_id in tqdm(channel_ids, desc="Extracting Channels"):
            response = youtube.search().list(
                part='snippet',
                channelId=channel_id,
                maxResults=10
            ).execute()

            for item in tqdm(response.get('items', []), desc="Extracting Videos"):
                video_id = item.get('id', {}).get('videoId')

                if video_id:
                    # Check if the video already exists in the database
                    cursor = conn.cursor()
                    query = "SELECT * FROM youtube_video WHERE video_id = ?"
                    cursor.execute(query, (video_id,))
                    result = cursor.fetchone()

                    if not result:
                        try:
                            video_data = youtube.videos().list(
                                part='snippet, statistics, contentDetails',
                                id=video_id
                            ).execute()

                            snippet = video_data['items'][0]['snippet']
                            statistics = video_data['items'][0]['statistics']
                            content_details = video_data['items'][0]['contentDetails']

                            transcript = get_video_transcript(youtube, video_id)

                            insert_query = """
                                INSERT INTO youtube_video 
                                (published_at, title, channel_id, thumbnails, channel_title, view_count, like_count, dislike_count, favorite_count, duration, video_id, transcript)
                                VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
                            """
                            cursor.execute(insert_query, (
                                snippet['publishedAt'],
                                snippet['title'],
                                snippet['channelId'],
                                snippet['thumbnails'],
                                snippet['channelTitle'],
                                statistics.get('viewCount', 0),
                                statistics.get('likeCount', 0),
                                statistics.get('dislikeCount', 0),
                                statistics.get('favoriteCount', 0),
                                content_details['duration'],
                                video_id,
                                transcript,
                            ))
                            conn.commit()

                            video = {
                                'publishedAt': snippet['publishedAt'],
                                'title': snippet['title'],
                                'channelId': snippet['channelId'],
                                'thumbnails': snippet['thumbnails'],
                                'channelTitle': snippet['channelTitle'],
                                'viewCount': statistics.get('viewCount', 0),
                                'likeCount': statistics.get('likeCount', 0),
                                'dislikeCount': statistics.get('dislikeCount', 0),
                                'favoriteCount': statistics.get('favoriteCount', 0),
                                'duration': content_details['duration'],
                                'videoId': video_id,
                                'transcript': transcript,
                            }

                            videos.append(video)

                        except HttpError as e:
                            # Handle API error
                            print(f"API Error: {str(e)}")
                else:
                    # Handle missing videoId
                    print("Skipping item without videoId")
    finally:
        conn.close()

    return render(request, 'youtube_data_app/youtube_data.html', {'videos': videos})
```